# How to use specific data from arrays - Example of click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I have the following JQuery code:

```
var test = new Array();

    $(".quiz_list_row").each(function(index){
            // Gets the data necessary to show game chosen
            $quiz_list_id = $(this).data("quizlistId");
            $quiz_level_reached = $(this).data("quizlevelReached");

                test.push($quiz_list_id,$quiz_level_reached);

            $(this).click(function(){
                alert("test: "+test);
            });

    });
```

The divs (using html5 to send data):

```
<div class="quiz_list_row" data-quizlist-id="1" data-quizlevel-reached="5">
    <div class="inline quiz_list_cell" id="quiz_list_cell_row0_id1">Quiz 1</div>
    <div class="inline quiz_list_cell" id="quiz_list_cell_row0_id2">Current level: 5</div>
</div>
<div class="quiz_list_row" data-quizlist-id="2" data-quizlevel-reached="7">
    <div class="inline quiz_list_cell" id="quiz_list_cell_row1_id1">Quiz 2</div>
    <div class="inline quiz_list_cell" id="quiz_list_cell_row1_id2">Current level: 7</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I need to find out how to use the data in the array `test` when the user clicks on a specific row (I want to use `$quiz_list_id` and `$quiz_level_reached`).

Comment: just so you know, you know that the items you're pushing into test is the id, then the quizlevel. I would assume you'd want them kept together instead of separate elements in the array. so your array would look like ['1','5','2','7'] in your example.

Comment: @kennypu, you're right! I decided to use david's answer, it's elegant and precise! hehe =) Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is a specific reason you're extracting the attributes and putting them into an array, I think you're taking some unecessary steps to achieving what you want. Take away the complexity from this, you have access to the data attributes with the `.data()` method at any time you have access to the elements jQuery object, one of those times is within the click handler itself.

```
var quizRows = $(".quiz_list_row");

quizRows.click(function(event) {

    var self = $(this);

    //As the element clicked on has it's data attributes defined
    //You would just need to retrieve it when the element is clicked on
    var id = self.data('quizlist-id'),
        level = self.data('quizlevel-reached');

    console.log("id is " + id);
    console.log("level is " + level);
}
```

Comment: It's funny that data('quizlist-id') should be data("quizlistId") to get the attributes, but it's like that. I haven't tried the method you spelled, though.
Anyway, that's an elegant way to solve the problem =) Thank you very much!!!